# How to structure a booking system in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

my goal is to create a reservation system in ruby(v=1.9.3p231) on rails (v=3.2.13).
It should be a reservation system for a hotel. It should be able to let you create rooms and perform some reservations for rooms. Of course you need some valdidations if a room is already reserved.

After many hours of trying out some stuff, I think my structur is failing. Could anybody please give me some hints, how to set up some reservation-system?

Tried two different ways:

1.
Created a search-form. It showed me any available room, but don't know how to do some specific requests. Especially how to use a time period (arrival - depature).

2.
Tried a directly reservation (that means booking and validation in one). Problem here is that I have no idea how to create correct databases and relations.

Anybody who could draft a layout of this project? Or tell me how many controllers are needed.

Thanks in advance.